# Adding additional text criteria to INDEX Query Flatten

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, flatten, google-query-language

Our team has a work calendar on Google Sheets to track company holidays. We're using a formula that counts the number of times the word 'Hol' appears in a row. The below snippet works, but I am also looking to count additional terms such as BH and Half. How would I add additional words to my array?

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(7:7="Hol", ROW(7:7), )), "select count(Col1) group by Col1"), "offset 2", ))
```

The ideal scenario is to tweak the text criteria part of the formula, but it's not counting the array correctly.

```
7:7="Hol","Half","BH"
```

I have made a test sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ODPNn81m8r2bfZgJqZR80ad5n1Wnsi513c40fQncsF0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(REGEXMATCH(7:7, "Hol|Half|BH"), ROW(7:7), )), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1"), "offset 2", ))
```

or `OR` logic if regex is a no go:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF((7:7="Hol")+(7:7="Half")+(7:7="BH"), ROW(7:7), )), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1"), "offset 2", ))
```

Comment: Hi @player0, the first option worked perfectly. It looks like I was very close. Thank you for helping. I have marked this as correct.

Comment: @player0, questions like this is why you can't give people this INDEX() thing instead of ARRAYFORMULA()  "Index Query Flatten"... nonsense!